# Requiring OpenGL 3.3 for a Blender 2.8 scene but not the application

Tags: file-format, error

I finished working on a scene last night in 2.8. This morning I tried to open the file and got a "Blender requires a graphics driver with at least OpenGL 3.3 support." error. I am able to open other 2.8 files without the error. If I load the start up file then open the scene I want to open it gives me the same error and Blender closes.

Could I have corrupted my file in some way?

Comment: Please report that behavior: https://developer.blender.org

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, so I have been fighting with this in many programs as well as blender, I think the problem is on Nvidia's side.  If you open the Nvidia Control Panel, you can specify the GPU to use for OpenGL.  This solution worked well for me and I don't have any more problems... yet.  Hope this helps.

Right click desktop > Nvidia Control Panel > Manage 3D Settings > OpenGL Rendering GPU > (specify only one, don't use Auto-Select)

Now click Apply and you should be good to go.

[image]